# How to calculate CRC in ISO CAN FD (new)?

Tags: crc, can-bus, crc16

I saw some message with the structure:

> Start of Frame - [ID, DLC, CRC, DATA] - End of Frame.

So, why is CRC  not after DATA? I think that case is easier to check?
I even don't know how they make this CRC value in CAR CAN:

| ID | Rx | DLC | CRC | DATA |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 03A0 | Rx | 16 | F4 7B | 2D 00 FF FF FF FF 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 |

I tried with very many polynomials but have had no result. Who can calculate this CRC from example data?

Answer (score 1):

[This web page](https://www.csselectronics.com/screen/page/can-fd-flexible-data-rate-intro/language/en) indicates that the CRC is *not* before the data. It's after it:

[image: four CAN frame layouts]

What documentation are you looking at that indicates the CRC is before the data?

[This page](https://www.can-cia.org/can-knowledge/can/crc/) provides the polynomials, but you need more information than just that to reproduce the calculation.

Answer (score 1):

> why is CRC not after DATA?

It is. The picture you posted is just some crappy dump from some logger tool, not a representation of a CAN FD frame. Google "CAN FD frame" and you get something like this:

[image]

([Source](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/CAN-FD-Frame-Format-from-9_fig1_320188400))

> How to calculate CRC in ISO CAN FD

Why would you? It is done in hardware by the CAN controller so you don't have to. It's a custom CRC-17 or CRC-21, see https://www.can-cia.org/can-knowledge/can/can-fd/. In general, don't run off to do strange things before you have studied the fundamental basics of CAN. And study classic CAN before you study CAN FD - it too has a hardware-checked CRC but a CRC-15.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else needs this info, it's on pages 32-33 (section 10.4.2.6) of standards document ISO 11898-1:2015. You can download this document from normstream.com for $39, also you can preview up to 4 pages free at sis.se. The reason I needed this info is to write a partial implementation of CAN-FD in software.